# Maximal function corresponding to a family of functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(f_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a family of measurable functions.  Under which criterion we can say that $\sup_{t\geq 0}\lvert f_t\rvert$ defines a measurable function? I am working in the following framework. Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff second countable topological group and $(\mu_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a family of probability measures on $G$ with $t\mapsto \mu_t$ $w^*$-continuous. Let $X$ be a standard Borel space equipped with a probability measure invariant under a measurable action by $G$. Define $\pi(\mu_t)f(x)\mathrel{:=}\int_Gf(g^{-1}x)d\mu_t(g)$ for $f\in L^p(X)$ for a fixed $1\leq p<\infty$. Then, we define $f_t:=\pi(\mu_t)f$.

I am looking for sufficient conditions under which the pointwise supremum $\sup_{t \ge 0} \lvert f_t\rvert$ is measurable and also well-defined in the sense that it does not depend on the equivalence class of $f$. And then some more sufficient conditions so that the supremum is in $L^p$.

Comment: I'm under the impression that the question is bit vague: one can find probably find various sufficient criteria in quite different contexts (for instance, it is sufficient if $f_t$ depends monotonically on $t$). Could you add a bit more context to the question so that we can see which type of assumptions would be interesting for you?

Comment: Under the assumptions stated, $\sup_{t \geq 0} |f_t|$ doesn't even have to be a function. Let $f_t = 1/|x - t|$ for $x \neq t$ and $0$ for $x = t$. Then each element is measurable. But for any $x \geq 0$ the supremum does not exist.

Comment: @WillieWong: Well, depending on what exactly the OP is looking for, it might be alright to consider functions that take the value $\infty$. But, of course, this is one more reason why more details would be very helpful.

Comment: I have given more details.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! So just to make sure that I understand correctly: are you really mostly interesting in measurability of the pointwise supremum? Or are you rather interested in the existence of a vector $0 \le h \in L^p$ that dominates the modulus of each $f_t$? I'm asking because if such an $h$ exists, then the equivalence classes of the $f_t$ *always* have a supremum in $L^p$ (which might not be a pointwise supremum, though).

Comment: If you let $X$ be the circle, and let $f(\theta) = 1/|\theta|^\epsilon$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$ and $\theta\in (-\pi,\pi)\setminus 0$ and define $f = 0$ on the two omitted points, you can take $G$ to be the circle group $U(1)$ acting on the circle by translations. You can let $\mu_t$ be the Dirac measure centered at $t$ mod $2\pi$. This I think satisfies all your conditions and recovers essentially the example in my previous comment.